# NSUserDefaults throws unexpected exception

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

In the app, the following method is called multiple times to find two random numbers, make a coupled item that is unique and has never been chosen before.

On line 16, Xcode throws a EXC_BAD_access thingy.
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(coupledItemSearchTerm) != nil

When i debugged my code, it successfully ran this line every time except the last time which it has to be executed. Its pretty weird.

EDIT: also tried the "objectForKey" too. Didn't work.

```
func randomGenerator()
{
    firstRandomItemId = self.productIds[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.productIds.count)))]
    secondRandomItemId = 0
    tempSecondRandomItemId = self.productIds[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.productIds.count)))]
    if tempSecondRandomItemId == firstRandomItemId
    {
        randomGenerator()
    }
    else
    {
        secondRandomItemId = tempSecondRandomItemId
    }
    coupledItemSearchTerm = "\(self.firstRandomItemId)\(self.secondRandomItemId)"

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(coupledItemSearchTerm) != nil
    {
        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(coupledItemSearchTerm) as Int == 1
        {
            println("\(coupledItemSearchTerm) was preferred")
            randomGenerator()
        }
    }

    if chosenCoupledItemIds.valueForKey(coupledItemSearchTerm) != nil
    {
        if chosenCoupledItemIds.valueForKey(coupledItemSearchTerm) as Int == 1
        {
            println("\(coupledItemSearchTerm) was chosen for showing couples")
            randomGenerator()
        }
    }
    else
    {
        chosenCoupledItemIds.setValue(1, forKey: coupledItemSearchTerm)
        coupledItemId.addObject(firstRandomItemId)
        coupledItemId.addObject(secondRandomItemId)
        coupledItemsId.addObject([coupledItemId[c*2],coupledItemId[c*2+1]])
        c++
        println(coupledItemSearchTerm)
    }

}
```

Please help me with it. I would be thankful as a 14 year old.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `valueForKey`. In the Apple Documentation its mentioned clearly that this returns value based "Accessor Search Pattern". If you are looking for existence of a key, you should rather user `objectForKey` which actually returns nil when the key doesn't exist.